# Is "partner content" on the SO blog supposed to have a special tag?

Tags: discussion, advertising, blog

I just read the ["Einstein Analytics and Go"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/10/07/how-salesforce-converted-einstein-analytics-to-go/?cb=1) article, on Stack Overflow blog. The disclaimer indicates content from partners will be indicated "with tags", yet the tags just below this disclaimer text don't mention partner content.

Does this refer to another kind of tagging? Or is it just missing a tag?

Here's a screen capture, with the text to which I'm referring highlighted and a nice, red oval where I think a tag should be.

> [image: screen capture of disclaimer text and tags]

Comment: Looks like I was wrong; Mark Amery found that [Salesforce is a client](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/salesforce), and so by the conditions in the disclaimer text there should be a tag there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

we did tag it with partner content and added the disclosure, since Salesforce is a client of SO. We forgot, however, that the section which appears under the article and is marked "Tags" actually draws from the "Categories" we select in our CMS, which is different than the tags.

To solve this I have created a new category entitled "Partner Content" and added it to the article. You can see that this now appears under the tags on this article.

Comment: Ah, so the UI mislabels categories by calling them *Tags*. Helpful :-)